# How to generalize a sequential COUNT() of chronological data without loops or cursors?

Tags: mysql, sql, nested-loops, database-cursor, procedural-programming

I have read all the arguments: Tell SQL what you want, not how to get it. Use set-based approaches instead of procedural logic. Avoid cursors and loops at all costs.

Unfortunately, I have been racking my brain for weeks and I can't figure out how to come up with a set-based approach to generating an iterative `COUNT` for sequential subsets of chronologically ordered data.

Here is the specific application of the problem I am working on.

I do football-related research using a database that comprises many years of play-by-play data, which is of course arranged chronologically by year, game, and play. The database is loaded onto a web server running MySQL 5.0.

The fields I need for this particular problem are contained in the `core` table. Here is some sample data from the relevant part of the table:

```
   GID | PID  | OFF | DEF | QTR | MIN | SEC | PTSO | PTSD
  --------------------------------------------------------
   121 | 2455 | ARI | CHI |   2 |   4 |  30 |   17 |   10
   121 | 2456 | ARI | CHI |   2 |   4 |  15 |   17 |   10 
   121 | 2457 | ARI | CHI |   2 |   3 |  53 |   17 |   10 
   121 | 2458 | ARI | CHI |   2 |   3 |  31 |   20 |   10
```

The columns represent, respectively: unique game identifier, unique play identifier, which team is on offense for that play, which team is on defense for that play, the quarter and time the play occurred, and the offense's and defense's scores going into the play. In other words, in (hypothetical) game 121, the Arizona Cardinals scored a field goal on play 2457 (i.e., going into play 2458).

What I want to do is go through several years' worth of data game by game, second by second, and count the number of times any possible score differential occurred at any given elapsed time. The following query arranges the data by seconds elapsed and score differential:

```
SELECT core.GID, core.PID, core.QTR, core.MIN, core.SEC, core.PTSO, core.PTSD, 
    ((core.QTR - 1) * 900 + (900-(core.MIN * 60 + core.SEC))) AS secEl, 
    core.PTSO - core.PTSD AS oDif, (core.PTSO - core.PTSD) * -1 AS dDif
FROM core 
ORDER BY secEl ASC, oDif ASC;
```

The result looks something like this:

```
   GID | PID    | OFF | DEF | QTR | MIN | SEC | PTSO | PTSD | secEl | oDif | dDif
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   616 | 100022 | CHI | MIN |   1 |  15 |  00 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0
   617 | 100169 | HOU | DAL |   1 |  15 |  00 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0
   618 | 100224 | PHI | SEA |   1 |  15 |  00 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0
   619 | 100303 | JAX | NYJ |   1 |  15 |  00 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0
```

Although that looks pretty, my goal is not to sort the data chronologically. Rather, I want to step sequentially through every one of the 4,500 possible seconds (four 15-minute quarters plus one 15-minute overtime period) in an NFL game and count the number of times every score differential has ever occurred in each one of those seconds.

In other words, I don't want to count just the number of times a team has been up by, say, 21 points at 1,800 seconds elapsed (i.e., the start of the second quarter) between 2002 and 2013. I want to count the number of times a team has been up by 21 points at *any* point in a game. On top of that, I want to do this for every score differential that has ever occurred (i.e., -50, -49, -48, ..., 0, 1, 2, ... 48, 49, 50, ...) for every second of every game.

This would be relatively easy to accomplish with a series of nested loops, but it wouldn't be the most reusable of code.

What I want to do is construct set logic that will `COUNT` the instances of each score differential that has occurred at every second of time elapsed *without* using loops or cursors. The results would be tabulated as follows:

```
   secondsElapsed | scoreDif | Occurrences
  -----------------------------------------
               10 |       -1 |          12
               10 |        0 |      125517
               10 |        1 |           0
               10 |        2 |           3
```

Here is a sample query for getting the total number of instances of a specific score differential (+21) at a specific time point (3,000 seconds elapsed):

```
SELECT ((core.QTR - 1) * 900 + (900-(core.MIN * 60 + core.SEC))) AS timeElapsed, 
    (core.PTSO - core.PTSD) AS diff, COUNT(core.PTSO - core.PTSD) AS occurrences 
FROM core 
WHERE ((core.QTR - 1) * 900 + (900-(core.MIN * 60 + core.SEC))) = 3000 
    AND ABS(core.PTSO - core.PTSD) = 21
```

That query returns the following results:

```
   timeElapsed | diff | occurrences
  ----------------------------------
          3000 |   21 |           5
```

Now I want generalize this query to count the instances of *every* differential at *every* second elapsed.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: COUNT(core.PTSO - core.PTSD) isn't doing what you think it's doing. I'm not exactly sure what you want it to do, but what it IS doing is counting records.. you may want to use sum() or some other operator, but not count, it's going to produce the same results for almost any parameter you pass in.

Comment: On a further note, I really cannot determine what results you're trying to get based on your description of the problem. I know for a fact that what you're trying to do can be done in a single (albeit long) SQL query in most RDBMS's-- if you're using mySQL you might have to resort to using temp tables, but otherwise, you should be good.

Comment: @Joe The tables are loaded into a SQL database on a web server. I am running the queries with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @rourke, what SQl database? Oracle, Sql Server, Postgre, mySQl? It makes a difference.

Comment: @JoeLove This database lists the results every play from every game for every season between 2000 and 2013. To give a specific example of what I am trying to find out, imagine I wanted to count the number of times in those seasons the offense was up by 21 points to start the third quarter (time elapsed = 1800 seconds). That would be a relatively straightforward query. But what I actually want to do is cycle through EVERY second from 0 to 3,600 seconds elapsed and count the number of times every possible score differential has ever occurred at each second.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please let me know the type of DB you're using and I'll post query for it.

Comment: @HLGEM The server is running MySql 5.

Comment: @JoeLove At the risk of redundancy, I will mention again that the server is running MySQL 5.x.

Comment: @HLGEM: Nitpicking: it's either Postgres or PostgreSQL, but not Postgre

Answer (score 0):

Your description is rather confusing but if you want to "COUNT all of the possible score differentials for every possible second without using loops or cursors" then I would do something like:

1) Build a work table (either a temporary table# or a Table data type@) and fill it with the time increments you want e.g.

```
   QTR | MIN | SEC |  
    1 |  00 |  01
    1 |  00 |  02
..
    1 |  01 |  59
    1 |  02 |  00
    1 |  02 |  01
    1 |  02 |  02
..
    4 |  15 |  59
```

2) You then use this as the basis of your query. Cross Join a list of the games you are interested in with the work table to give you a table of every game and every minute in that game.

3) With the result of (2) left join your query above back into it?

With this result set you can then look at a whole game and sum\count as neccessary without having to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will cure your problem, but you could try using row_number over a partition...

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <column> ORDER BY <column>) AS aColumn, aColumn FROM aTable
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant approach, but unfortunately `ROW_NUMBER()` is not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using a sub-query and two variables to define the time point and another to define the point difference.

The query then returns the Diff, then the amount of times the offensive side had it, followed by the defensive side and total times.

```
SET @Diff INT = 7;
SET @Seconds INT = 1530;

SELECT ABS(core.PTSO - core.PTSD) AS diff, SUM(CASE WHEN core.PTSO - core.PTSD <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OffensiveTimes, SUM(CASE WHEN core.PTSO - core.PTSD >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DefensiveTimes, SUM(1) TotalTimes

FROM (SELECT core.GID, core.PID, core.QTR, core.MIN, core.SEC, core.PTSO, core.PTSD, 
    ((core.QTR - 1) * 900 + (900-(core.MIN * 60 + core.SEC))) AS secEl, 
    core.PTSO - core.PTSD AS oDif, (core.PTSO - core.PTSD) * -1 AS dDif
FROM core 
) core
WHERE secEl = @Seconds    AND ABS(core.PTSO - core.PTSD) = @Diff
GROUP BY ABS(core.PTSO - core.PTSD);
```

This returns this for the small dataset you gave

7 diff, 0 OffensiveTimes, 1 DefensiveTimes, 1 Times

Hope that was what you were looking for :)

Comment: This query looks promising, but it returns a syntax error. Is it not compatible with MySql 5.x?

Comment: Ah, that was for MSSql, I'll try make a working version for MySQL by the weekend, sounds like a fun exercise :)

Comment: Take a look again @RourkeDecker , I checked it in SQLFiddle with the same test data set and got the working result. Difference was using SET for the variable declaration and semi-colons after every statement.